# Individual User Account entre projetos MVC e WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api, autenticação

Possuo um projeto MVC com Individual User Accounts, utilizo Roles para gestão de acessos e tudo funciona bem.
Recentemente tive a necessidade de criar um gerenciador de arquivos em outro servidor, criei um projeto WEB API e me comunico via HttpClient, a conexão funciona porém como efetuo validações de acesso no WEB API me baseando no usuário já logado no projeto MVC?

Segue conexão que utilizo para excluir um arquivo.

MVC 5:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "DeleteFile")]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {            
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
        using (var cliente = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            string urlAPI = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL_WEBAPI"];
            urlAPI = string.Format("{0}delete//{1}", urlAPI, id);

            var result = await cliente.DeleteAsync(urlAPI);
            if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return false;
        }
    }
```

WEB API

```
    [RoutePrefix("files")]
    public class FileController : ApiController
    {  
        [HttpDelete, Route("delete/{id}")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
            HttpStatusCode result = await FileBLL.DeleteFileAsync(id);
            return StatusCode(result);
        }
    }
```

Se eu tento utilizar o [Authorize] no WEB API a conexão não funciona, existe alguma forma de manter o login em meu projeto MVC e na conexão via HttpClient o WEB API entender que existe um usuário no contexto?

Answer (score 2):

Recentemente tive que realizar isso.
Você pode utilizar **Bearer Token Authentication** para isso.

Basicamente você deve gerar um Token JWT que você deve armazenar em seu MVC5.
Eu gero o token quando me logo na própria WEB API e depois guardo esse token para usar nas requisições.

Quando for realizar requisições para a WEB API você deve passar esse Token como Header Authorization Bearer *tokengerado*.

Aqui segue um ótimo projeto utilizando .NET FRAMEWORK de WEBAPI utilizando autenticação JWT.
https://github.com/cuongle/WebApi.Jwt

Caso esteja utilizando .NET CORE segue outro link muito útil.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/10/27/bearer-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/

Espero ter ajudado.